# How do I go about waiting for two DynamoDB calls to finish before executing new function?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to execute two asynchronous functions to DynamoDB. 
I will need the return data from both before continuing with the following step which is sending an email that contains their data.
How do I tackle this issue?

I'm using the following code:

```
var productParams = {
      TableName: productsTable,
      FilterExpression: 'client = :this_client',
      ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':this_client': "someclient" }
    };

    dynamoClient.scan(productParams, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to query. Error:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
      } else {
        console.log("Query succeeded.");
        data.Items.forEach(item => {
          products.push(item)
        });
      }
    });

    var retailerParams = {
      TableName: retailersTable,
      FilterExpression: 'leadTime = :this_leadTime',
      ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':this_leadTime': 42 }
    };

    dynamoClient.scan(retailerParams, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to query. Error:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
      } else {
        console.log("Query succeeded.");
        data.Items.forEach(item => {
          retailers.push(item)
        });
      }
    });

    var email = {
      "Source": "somemail@gmail.com",
      "Template": "some_template",
      "Destination": {
        "ToAddresses": ["somemail@gmail.com"]
      },
      "TemplateData": `{somedata}`
    }
    await ses.sendTemplatedEmail(email).promise();
```

Comment: With few exceptions, I don't think you should use the original ddb.scan() or ddb.xyz() methods any more. Instead you should probably use the promisified variants, such as ddb.scan.promise(). Then you can await the results, or use Promise features such as Promise.all(). See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/using-promises.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert both DynamoDB calls into promises (by chaining `scan` calls with `.promise()` calls) and `await` them using `Promise.all` before sending the email:

```
var productParams = {
  TableName: productsTable,
  FilterExpression: 'client = :this_client',
  ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':this_client': "someclient" }
};

const productsPromise = dynamoClient.scan(productParams).promise()
  .then(data => {
    data.Items.forEach(item => {
      products.push(item)
    });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error("Unable to query. Error:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
  });

var retailerParams = {
  TableName: retailersTable,
  FilterExpression: 'leadTime = :this_leadTime',
  ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':this_leadTime': 42 }
};

const retailersPromise = dynamoClient.scan(retailerParams).promise()
  .then(data => {
    console.log("Query succeeded.");
    data.Items.forEach(item => {
      retailers.push(item)
    });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error("Unable to query. Error:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
  });


await Promise.all([
  productsPromise,
  retailersPromise
]);

var email = {
  "Source": "somemail@gmail.com",
  "Template": "some_template",
  "Destination": {
    "ToAddresses": ["somemail@gmail.com"]
  },
  "TemplateData": `{somedata}`
}

await ses.sendTemplatedEmail(email).promise();
```